# Property of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

In classroom I have copied a property of subspaces, very usefull to solve certain kind of problems. It says:

$$\left.\begin{matrix}
S\subseteq T\\{}\\ \dim S = \dim T\end{matrix}\right\} \Rightarrow S = T$$
where S and T are subspaces of V.

Well, I whip through several textbooks (Grossman, Poole, Larson, Anton) to find the demonstration, but I dind't find it. So, can you tell where can I find it? (And why it's not explicit y some texts?) Thanks

Comment: That property is true for *finite* dimensional spaces

Answer (score 1):

For finite dimensional spaces : let $\;A:=\{s_1,...,s_n\}\;$ be a basis of $\;S\;$ . Then it is **also** a basis of $\;T\;$ because $\;S\le T\;$ *and also* $\;\dim S=\dim T\;$ , so

$$S=\text{Span}\,A=T$$